# Am I allowed to create a cumulative frequency distribution from non-normally distributed data?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, median

I have data gathered from a circadian rhythm experiment and I like to present this data as a percentile cumulative frequency distribution (CFD%), because I think this is a clean way to present the data and it clearly shows a 'shift to the left' of the experimental group.

However, the data is not normally distributed, so I wonder if it makes any sense to create a CDF(%) except for visualization purposes. Unlike a normal Gaussian distribution, the 50% of the CDF% still seems to correspond to the calculated median of the non-normally distributed data set, is this coincidence or is this simply how the CDF% works.

So the simple question is:
Does the 50% line of a percentile cumulative frequency distribution correspond with the Median of a data set, even if the data set is not normally distributed?

Comment: Certainly allowed, and not just for visualization. Also, it is always true that the median is the 50% percentile. That's a definition. It's true for non-normal and skewed distributions too. A different question is whether you would be better off showing and indeed analysing your data on a transformed scale.

Comment: Depends on your audience but "Cumulative distribution" is enough words for most statistical purposes.